# Create a file from parsed string, NASM linux 32 bit

Tags: linux, x86, nasm, 32-bit

I'm trying to create a file from a parsed string, but can't seem to find much information on the topic.  An example of what I'm trying to do is take this URL from stdin:

www.stackoverflow.com/test.txt

and create a file called test.txt

I've parsed the string, but I am unable to create a file after that.  Any ideas or resources on how to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Linux has the [`sys_open`](https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) system call, the CLib [wrapper](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) serves as a documentation for the system call itself.

Comment: Thanks Margaret.  I thought there was a system call to do this, but didn't think of sys_open.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start with how you'd do it in C, and if that isn't already just a wrapper for a system call, figure out what system call the library uses.  e.g. the man page for ISO C `fopen(3)` has a see also `open(2)` for the POSIX `open()` function, which is directly implemented as a system call on Linux (like most man-page section 2 things).